# Как сделать чтобы размер текста менялся в зависимости от размера окна браузера?

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, css3

В общем-то вопрос в заголовке :)

Comment: Медиа-запросами CSS, например.

Comment: Если хочется плавно, то вот здесь подробно расписано https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/315196/

Comment: Вам дали несколько ответов. Если вам какой-либо подошёл, можете отметить какой-либо из ответов как принятый? Если никакой не подходит, то оставьте, пожалуйста, уточняющий комментарий, чем вам не подошёл ни один из ответов.

Answer (score 1):

либо указать размеры текста в 'em', либо относительно ширины браузера 'vw' или высоты 'vh'. Учитывайте что в данном случае, текст может быть как очень крупным, так и очень мелким, для ограничения действий лучше использовать запросы @media, которые будут менять этот параметр при достижении какого-либо размера браузера.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body { font-size: 0.9rem; }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 900px) {
  body { font-size: 0.8rem; }
}
@media (max-width: 899px) {
  body { font-size: 0.7rem; }
}
```

Comment: @media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body { font-size: 0.9rem; }
} - этот запрос лишний, так как body {font-size: 0.9rem} - применяется во всех не перечисленных ниже запросах

Comment: @Юрий, а сейчас не лишний

Comment: ))) сейчас нет.